# JavaScript / TypeScript issue with HTML

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have been developing in JavaScript a long time ago. Lately I was asked to do some work with client side scripting so I decided to look into TypeScript, to avoid some of JavaScript pitfalls.
My problem is probably basic but I could not find an answer that would be clear to me with my lack of TypeScript / new JavaScript development over the last 10 years.
Here it is -
I have three files -

```
1. index.html
2. Globals.ts
3. Drawings.ts
```

Index.html is the file to be served, in it a JavaScript will arrange and interact with the user.
Globals.ts - simply contain my global variables / constants
Drawing.ts - contain the Drawing functions for the data, it is referencing `globals.ts` for the global definitions, with this statement
`/// <reference path="globals.ts"/>.`

In index.html I use the SCRIPT tag with src='Drawings.ts' right under the HEAD Tag.

```
<SCRIPT lang='JavaScript' src='Drawing.ts'></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT lang='JavaScript'>local code goes here</SCRIPT>
```

All the globals in the Global.ts are declared with the word var and assigned a value, like this -

```
    var x_scale_h_offset = 15;
    var y_scale_v_offset  = 15;
    var g_general_margin  = 10;
    var g_std_font_height  = 10;
    var dpi = 1;
```

After checking for document complete status I call the init_d() function from Drawings.ts which looks like this -

```
function init_d()
{
    dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
}
```

I get a runtime Uncaught exception dpi is not defined.

I was under the impression that variables declared in a file which are not part of an object are global to all scripts.
I also assume - which I might be wrong - that this reference statement
`/// <reference path="globals.ts"/>` will cause `Globals.ts` to be loaded.

Can someone explain - in simplicity - what am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Regards

Comment: You will likely need to build the TypeScript (.ts) to vanilla JavaScript (.js) as there are likely some TS specific things that the browser doesn't support like the reference path

Comment: Why would you want to serve TS files? Also why use the ancient `lang='JavaScript'` ? I would expect `<script src="Drawings.ts.run.through.babel.and.served.as.text.slash.javascript.js"></script>`

Comment: But you can't do `<script src='Drawing.ts'>`. Browsers don't (yet?) understand Typescript (or maybe they kiiiind of could, IF the TS file contains only JS code with no typings and nothing Typescript-specific)

Comment: It seems that the browser find the Drawings.ts, as I do get to the init_d function that resides there, but it seems that the globals.ts is where the problem occurs, as the dpi is declared there and I get runtime error on it not being recognaized.
```Why would you want to serve TS files? Also why use the ancient lang='JavaScript' ? I would expect <script src="Drawings.ts.run.through.babel.and.served.as.text.slash.javascript.js"></script>```
I am not familiar with this syntax, like I said I guess I'm missing 10 years of changes and development of JavaScript.